# fsck not running on root partition, despite max time reached

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, root, fsck

My raspberry pi complains in /var/log/syslog "kernel: [   19.931374] EXT4-fs (sda2): warning: checktime reached, running e2fsck is recommended". So, fsck should run at boot, but it does not.

OS: Linux blueberry 5.10.63-v7+ ("Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)")

Based on various suggestions on this and other fora, I checked the following:

- check time is truly expired:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | grep 'Next check after'
Next check after:         Tue Nov 23 13:22:15 2021
```

- /boot/cmdline includes fsck.mode=force and fsck.repair=yes:

```
$ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=2ac02a4b-399a-4bae-88a5-f63f1f743ed9 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes ipv6.disable=1 rootwait
```

- pass parameter in fstab is not 0

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid/2ac02a4b-399a-4bae-88a5-f63f1f743ed9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 26 12:35 /dev/disk/by-partuuid/2ac02a4b-399a-4bae-88a5-f63f1f743ed9 -> ../../sda2
$ grep '2ac02a4b-399a-4bae-88a5-f63f1f743ed9' /etc/fstab
PARTUUID=2ac02a4b-399a-4bae-88a5-f63f1f743ed9 / etc4 defaults 0       1
```

- no setting 'broken_system_clock' in either of the two conf files (one does not exist)

```
$ grep 'broken' /etc/mke2fs.conf
$ ls /etc/e2fsck.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/e2fsck.conf': No such file or directory
```

What else should I tweak to run fsck at boot to check the root partition?

##################################
Update:

Same problem when using count-based fsck: max mount count is exceeded, but fsck is not run at boot. So it has nothing to do with the published system clock bug?

Further, it seems that systemd-fsck-root.service is never run (on another RPi, the status of this service is reported as 'Active: active (exited)', as expected for a oneshot service with RemainAfterExit):

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-fsck-root.service
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of systemd-fsck-root.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● systemd-fsck-root.service - File System Check on Root Device
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-fsck-root.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-fsck-root.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-fsck-root.service(8)
```

**The warning is surprising, as there was no change since the latest reboot. Could this be a hint, what is going wrong?**
The content of the service file:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
pi@blueberry ~ $ sudo systemctl cat systemd-fsck-root.service
# /lib/systemd/system/systemd-fsck-root.service
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=File System Check on Root Device
Documentation=man:systemd-fsck-root.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=local-fs.target shutdown.target
Wants=systemd-fsckd.socket
After=systemd-fsckd.socket
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=!/
ConditionPathExists=!/run/initramfs/fsck-root

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-fsck
TimeoutSec=0
```

**Suggestion to add 'ro' to the boot parameters** (see comment): I understand that sda2 (the root partition) is initially mounted 'ro', the default. See dmesg output (shortened). Nevertheless, I tried adding 'ro' to /boot/cmdline.txt; fsck is still not run on the root partition and the status of systemd-fsck-root.service is still 'inactive (dead)'.

```
$ dmesg
...
[    8.859189] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    9.743724]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    9.756744] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   10.860996]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[   10.873495] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   11.041224] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   11.054685] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 8:2.
...
[   20.406869] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   20.427245] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   20.446837] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   20.465100] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[   21.008905] i2c /dev entries driver
[   21.725644] EXT4-fs (sda2): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
[   21.783533] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
...
```

Comment: Maybe you have to specify `ro` on the kernel command line? Not entirely up-to-date on the specifics here.

Comment: @Daniel-B: Thanks for your suggestion. Another RPi where systemd-fsck-root.service is active and the root filesystem is checked, has no 'ro' on the commandline; 'ro' is also the default: [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113645/what-is-the-difference-between-adding-ro-to-boot-cmdline-txt-vs-etc-fstab). Indeed, dmesg lists a read-only mount, later a remount; I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** (avoiding to unplug the harddisk that is buried behind a cupboard)

I copied the entire root partition so that I can now boot from either of the two partitions, and fsck the unused partition. In detail:

- create a new partition on the same harddisk with an ext4 filesystem
- mount the new filesystem
- rsync -a -X -A -H -x --noatime -u --human-readable /
- modify /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/fstab to refer to the new partition instead of the current root partition
- reboot
- manually fsck the former root partition (now unused and unmounted)
- reverse changes to /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/fstab
- reboot